# Getting error "Argument 1 passed to Modules\\Admin\\Events\\"

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in laravel. I am creating mailer in laravel in which i created event for it. But from postman when i am hitting the api, i am getting error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Modules\\Admin\\Events\\NewsLetterSubscribeEvent::__construct() must be an instance of App\\Models\\NewsletterSubscription, array given, called in /home/ashish/projects/backend/laravel-backend/app/Repositories/NewsletterSubscriptionRepository.php on line 25",
```

What can be issue, i imported all classes, but still getting the error.

this is my code

> repository

```
class NewsletterSubscriptionRepository extends EloquentBaseRepository
{
    public $model = NewsletterSubscription::class;

    public function create($data)
    {
        try{
            DB::beginTransaction();

            event(new NewsLetterSubscribeEvent($data));
            DB::commit();
        } catch(Exception $exception){
            DB::rollBack();
            throw $exception;
        }
        return parent::create($data); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

    }
}
```

> event file

```
<?php


namespace Modules\Admin\Events;

use App\Models\NewsletterSubscription;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Modules\Admin\Mail\NewsLetterSubscribeMail;

class NewsLetterSubscribeEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * SendMailToAgentEvent constructor.
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function __construct(NewsletterSubscription $user)
    {
        dd($user);
        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new NewsLetterSubscribeMail($user));
    }
}
```

> model

```
<?php


namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class NewsletterSubscription extends Model
{
    const ACTIVE = 1;
    const INACTIVE = 0;
    protected $table = 'newsletter_subscription';
    protected $casts = [
        'is_active' => 'int'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'is_active'
    ];


}
```

Am i forgetting any namespace, or i am doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO .. what is `NewsletterSubscriptionRepository` line no .25 .?

Comment: @KamleshPaul thanks. its event(new NewsLetterSubscribeEvent($data));

Comment: In the `__construct` function in `NewsLetterSubscribeEvent`, you specified the argument `$user` to be an instance of `NewsletterSubscription` but the `$data` in `event(new NewsLetterSubscribeEvent($data));` is an array.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new instance of `NewsletterSubscription` in the `create` function before dispatching the event?

Answer (score 0):

Error is saying `must be an instance of NewsletterSubscription` but you are passing array to fix this

```php
public function __construct($user)  // remove NewsletterSubscription  from here 
{ 
    dd($user);
    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new NewsLetterSubscribeMail($user));
}
```

or

```php
class NewsletterSubscriptionRepository extends EloquentBaseRepository
{
    public $model = NewsletterSubscription::class;

    public function create($data)
    {
        $newsLetterSubscribeEvent  = null;
        try{
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $newsLetterSubscribeEvent = NewsletterSubscription::create($data); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
            event(new NewsLetterSubscribeEvent($newsLetterSubscribeEvent)); // passing model instace
            DB::commit();
        } catch(Exception $exception){
            DB::rollBack();
            throw $exception;
        }
        
        return $newsLetterSubscribeEvent;

    }
}
```